# Is normalization of input variables necessary for problem using second order algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization, gradient-descent

I have a question about normalizing input variables in optimization. While it's widely acknowledged that normalization is crucial for first-order optimization algorithms like gradient descent, I'm uncertain about its necessity for second-order algorithms such as L-BFGS-B or Newton's method, as well as Conjugate Gradient (CG), which has the ability to search fully in one direction. Could someone provide insights into whether variable normalization is essential when using these second-order optimization techniques? I appreciate any clarification on this matter. Thank you.

Comment: Strictly speaking it isn't necessary. It's not necessary in your second paragraph either. This question is a bit vague and probably off topic for SO.

Comment: thanks a lot, I reorganized  my question

Comment: This still seems off topic. You appear to be asking for original research, so the solution would be a book or paper. What would be an acceptable answer for you?